# Why does it say 'int32 array index expected'?

Tags: c#, json

So I just want to make a command that gets accounts' rank and pp and order them by rank and the question is this is even possible or am I just doing nonsense again?

```
[Command("rank")]
public async Task RankList([Remainder]string usernames = null)
{
    string[] usernameList = usernames.Split(",");
    string url = $"";

    WebClient profile = new WebClient();
    int countUsernames = usernameList.Count();
    string[] ranking = new string[countUsernames];
    dynamic[] ranks = new dynamic[countUsernames];
    string[] pp_rank = new string[countUsernames];
    float[] pp_raw = new float[countUsernames];

    for (int i = 0; i < usernameList.Count(); i++)
    {
        url = $"https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user?k={k}&u={usernameList[i]}";
        ranking[i] = profile.DownloadString(url);
        ranks[i] = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ranking[i]);
        pp_rank[i] = (string)ranks[0]["pp_rank"]; 
        pp_raw[i] = ranks[0]["pp_raw"]; 
    }
}
```

I get the error message:

> Accessed JArray values with invalid key: "pp_rank" Int32 arrey index
>   expected

The basic idea is that if I get usernames I can make a list of them ordered by rank and I just want to do that, but I don't know if this is even possible!

Comment: Indices are of type `int`. `"pp_rank"` is a `string`.

Comment: It looks like the json objects you are stuff into each `ranks` slot is an array, and you're trying to access by property name without having first selected an array element.

Answer (score 2):

`ranks` is apparently an array of `JArray` (`dynamic` just defers type checking until runtime). `JArray` emulates a normal C# array, which cannot be indexed by strings, only numbers (hence the error).

You need to index into the array (giving a `JObject`) then you can try to get properties:

```
(string)ranks[0][0]["pp_rank"]; //Get the first element of the array's pp_prank
```

That being said, this is really hard to read or write correctly. If you deserialized into a class that represents the data you are getting back, you wouldn't have these kinds of mistakes.